# Restforce Assistance

Tags: rest, ruby

I'm new to ruby and I've managed to connect my SalesForce app via oauth. I was following a couple of examples in [Restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce).

And I made the following query:

```
accounts = $cliente.query("select id from Account limit 25")
```

What type of data is accounts? I want to itereate through it and check the data retreived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a [Restforce::Collection](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce/blob/04ade41037ff952b70e1d6c2855906d3dd43eab1/lib/restforce/collection.rb), which is [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html), and so also provides an [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) function. You can just use the query result like you'd do with a typical collection:

```
accounts.each { |record| /* something goes here */ }
```

Since it mixes in Enumerable, you can also use verbs like `any?` and `all?`.